# An identity for $J_n(x)$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

It was much easier and faster to upload the image of my proof. I got it down to where the question marks are. But I can not seem to figure out how to get the anti-derivative to evaluate the integral. Can anyone help?

or maybe I made a mistake elsewhere.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the title edit... I was just working on some number theory stuff before changing to this calculus...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the identity

$$\color{red}{2\sin(A) \sin(B) = \cos(A-B) - \cos(A+B)}$$

---

You are given that
$$J_n(x) = \dfrac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(nt-x\sin(t))dt = \dfrac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(x\sin(t)-nt)dt$$
We hence have
$$J_n'(x) = \dfrac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sin(x\sin(t)-nt)\cdot \sin(t)dt \,\,\,\, (\spadesuit)$$
Now recall that
$$2\sin(A) \sin(B) = \cos(A-B) - \cos(A+B)$$
Hence, we have
$$\sin(x\sin(t)-nt)\cdot \sin(t) = \dfrac{\cos(x\sin(t)-nt-t)-\cos(x\sin(t)-nt+t)}2 \,\,\,\, (\clubsuit)$$
Plugging $(\clubsuit)$ in $(\spadesuit)$, we obtain
\begin{align}
J_n'(x) & = \dfrac12\left(\dfrac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos(x\sin(t)-(n+1)t) dt - \dfrac1{\pi} \int_0^{\pi}\cos(x\sin(t)-(n-1)t) dt\right)\\
& = \dfrac12\left(J_{n+1}(x) - J_{n-1}(x)\right)
\end{align}
Hence, we obtain
$$2J_n'(x) = J_{n+1}(x) - J_{n-1}(x)$$

Comment: why can you say this? seems like a negative is missing. $$J_n(x) = \dfrac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(nt-x\sin(t))dt = \dfrac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(x\sin(t)-nt)dt$$

Comment: @Brad Why can I say what? Also, no negative is missing since $\cos(-y) = \cos(y)$.

Comment: I was wondering why you could just switch the order inside the $cos$ but the property you just said sums it up. Thanks